# JSTestDriver concurrent tests

Tags: javascript, testing, continuous-integration, js-test-driver

I've been evaluating JSTestDriver, and it seems to be working well. I want to use it in a continuous integration environment, and I want to know if multiple projects can be testing against the same JSTestDriver server at the same time.

So my configuration is I have 1 JSTestDriver server with 3 different browsers captured. Can multiple projects run their test suites against that same server? Or is a JSTestDriver server only designed to run one test suite at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I am using JSTestDriver in a continious integration environment, too. Unfortunately, I noted that JSTestDriver gets instable when running for a long time, which means that we need to restart the JSTestDriver server process and reconnect all browser slaved. I found this behavior also described in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/js-test-driver/8EXVL-Rl4Ys).

Therefore, we are restarting the JSTestDriver before each build to make sure it is working. That means that you can not use one JSTestDriver for all builds because it would might be restarted by one build while the other build wants to run tests on it. Therefore, every build plan in your Continious Integration should have an own instance of JSTestDriver to use, and developers should use their own instances running on their local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The conf file specifies all the files needed to do a test run. The better question might be if your able to run multiple conf files at the same time. Personally I would just include all the files needed to be tested in one conf file. But if that's not an option here are some links.

Check this link out: (Grunt-JsTestDriver)
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-jstestdriver
https://github.com/rickyclegg/this/blob/master/node_modules/grunt-jstestdriver/README.md

Comment: Here is some info that might help also:
http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/CommandLineFlags (ctrl+f "Apr 26, 2012")